# InstaPy login , python

Tags: python-3.x, instapy

I started learning the InstaPy module.
I tried to learn how to login on to my Instagram account, but it won't work.
Here is the code.

```
from instapy import InstaPy 
session = InstaPy(username='' ,password='') session.login()
```

And this is the error I got.

**selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line**

Answer (score 0):

You must share the configuration env info, the instapy version (installed from git or pip), and the template was used to start the session.
It could be that the bot was not able to locate the browser binary path, how ever it's hard to understand your problem due to the lack of info.

Comment: Hi dude, I installed it from pip.But i still don't know why It doesn't work

Comment: You must share the complete configuration and the template for starting the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with [quickstart script](https://github.com/InstaPy/instapy-quickstart).And after you learn to login successfully with quickstart.py then try to play with templates.

> with smart_run(session):#under **this** line, you can make changes whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

#USE FIREFOX

```
from instapy import InstaPy

browser = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

session = InstaPy(username='XXXXXXX',
                  password='XXXXXXX',
                  browser_executable_path=browser)
session.login()
```